# How to group by a key data in a Json

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript, angular-material

I need to group by the results in a Json to show it nicely like requested by our product owner.

I have a JSON organiced like this:

```
    {"QuestionId":5097,"OwnerId":187957,"CultureId":"es-CL",
"Section":"Información Impositiva \/ Tributaria","Text":"Recibo"},
    {"QuestionId":6587,"OwnerId":187957,"CultureId":"es-CL",
"Section":"Preguntas Específicas","Text":"Por favor, cargue el documento"},
    {"QuestionId":6065,"OwnerId":187957,"CultureId":"es-CL",
"Section":"Preguntas específicas","Text":"Cargue una copia de suministro."},
    {"QuestionId":5393,"OwnerId":187957,"CultureId":"es-CL",
"Section":"Responsabilidad Social Empresarial y Anticorrupción","Text":"En caso afirmativo, cargue su política anticorrupción"},
    {"QuestionId":6584,"OwnerId":187957,"CultureId":"es-CL",
"Section":"Preguntas Específicas","Text":"Por favor, cargue el documento"}
```

What I want to achieve is group by the key called "Section" in my JSON and obtain as a result something like this:

```
Section : "Información Impositiva / Tributaria"
0
QuestionId : 5097
OwnerId : 187957
CultureId : "es-CL"
Text : "Recibo"
Section : "Preguntas Específicas"
1
QuestionId : 6587
OwnerId : 187957
CultureId : "es-CL"
Text : "Por favor, cargue el documento"
2
QuestionId : 6065
OwnerId : 187957
CultureId : "es-CL"
Text : "Cargue una copia de suministro."
```

My expected output  would be to show on my html template somthing like:

```
Información Impositiva / Tributaria
     Recibo
Preguntas Específicas
     Por favor, cargue el documento
     Cargue una copia de suministro.
```

Key things to consider, I´m working with Angular material. The group by filters that we have in our code have been customized and the function _,groupby() does not what one would like (I can show you what the result is, if wanted)

Thanks in advance for all the help and please let me know if I can improve the question in any way.

Comment: Can you share the expected output?

Comment: uiTeam324, Just did per your request. Hope it is more clear want I want to achieve.

Comment: Check this out - https://medium.com/@edisondevadoss/javascript-group-an-array-of-objects-by-key-afc85c35d07e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group the data with reduce function (alternative: lodash groupBy) and then iterate the data in template

stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nlhba4?file=src/app/app.component.html

Code from stackblitz:

```
questionGroups;

  ngOnInit() {
    const questions = [
      {"QuestionId":5097,"OwnerId":187957,"CultureId":"es-CL",
  "Section":"Información Impositiva \/ Tributaria","Text":"Recibo"},
      {"QuestionId":6587,"OwnerId":187957,"CultureId":"es-CL",
  "Section":"Preguntas Específicas","Text":"Por favor, cargue el documento"},
      {"QuestionId":6065,"OwnerId":187957,"CultureId":"es-CL",
  "Section":"Preguntas específicas","Text":"Cargue una copia de suministro."},
      {"QuestionId":5393,"OwnerId":187957,"CultureId":"es-CL",
  "Section":"Responsabilidad Social Empresarial y Anticorrupción","Text":"En caso afirmativo, cargue su política anticorrupción"},
      {"QuestionId":6584,"OwnerId":187957,"CultureId":"es-CL",
  "Section":"Preguntas Específicas","Text":"Por favor, cargue el documento"}
    ];

    this.questionGroups = questions.reduce((acc, question) => {
      if (!acc[question.Section]) {
        acc[question.Section] = [];
      }

      acc[question.Section].push(question);

      return acc;
    },{});
  }
```

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let kv of questionGroups | keyvalue">
  {{ kv.key }}
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let question of kv.value">
      {{ question.Text }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</ng-container>
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
let data = [{
  "QuestionId": 5097, "OwnerId": 187957, "CultureId": "es-CL",
  "Section": "Información Impositiva \/ Tributaria", "Text": "Recibo"
},
{
  "QuestionId": 6587, "OwnerId": 187957, "CultureId": "es-CL",
  "Section": "Preguntas Específicas", "Text": "Por favor, cargue el documento"
},
{
  "QuestionId": 6065, "OwnerId": 187957, "CultureId": "es-CL",
  "Section": "Preguntas específicas", "Text": "Cargue una copia de suministro."
},
{
  "QuestionId": 5393, "OwnerId": 187957, "CultureId": "es-CL",
  "Section": "Responsabilidad Social Empresarial y Anticorrupción", "Text": "En caso afirmativo, cargue su política anticorrupción"
},
{
  "QuestionId": 6584, "OwnerId": 187957, "CultureId": "es-CL",
  "Section": "Preguntas Específicas", "Text": "Por favor, cargue el documento"
}]



var outObject = data.reduce((a, b) => {

  let keyToGroup = (b['Section'].toLocaleLowerCase());
  (a[keyToGroup] ? a[keyToGroup] : (a[keyToGroup] = null || [])).push(b);
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(outObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either lodash.groupBy() or [this version on 1loc.dev](https://1loc.dev/#group-an-array-of-objects-by-a-key) then create a nested array based on the keys of the object:

```js
const grouped = _.groupBy(questionsArray, 'section'); // Create an object grouped by your section key
const nested = Object.keys(grouped) // Get all keys (section names)
  .map(key => ({section: key, questions: grouped[key]})) // Create an array objects

/*
[
  {"QuestionId":5097,"OwnerId":187957,"CultureId":"es-CL","Section":"Información Impositiva \/ Tributaria","Text":"Recibo"},
  {"QuestionId":6587,"OwnerId":187957,"CultureId":"es-CL","Section":"Preguntas Específicas","Text":"Por favor, cargue el documento"},
]

would become

[
  {
    section: "Información Impositiva \/ Tributaria",
    questions: [
      {"QuestionId":5097,"OwnerId":187957,"CultureId":"es-CL","Text":"Recibo"}
    ]
  },
  {
    section: "Preguntas Específicas",
    questions: [
      {"QuestionId":6587,"OwnerId":187957,"CultureId":"es-CL","Text":"Por favor, cargue el documento"}
    ]
  }
]
*/
```

I think this is your intended output

Answer (score 0):

1st Way:

```
let grouppedArray = data.reduce((r, a) => {
  r[a.Section] = {...r[a.Section] || [], a};
  return r;
}, {});
```

2nd Way with underscore.js

```
let grouppedArray=_.groupBy(data,'Section');
console.log("group", group);
```